# How to get Package installation date in ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, debian, package

I want to get package installation date in Ubuntu.
In fedora and opensuse, i am getting it through by

`popen("rpm -qi 'Package-name'")`

But don't get installation date in Ubuntu for package.
There is a option by parsing file

`"/var/log/dpkg.log"`

But i don't want to get from log file, In any case, if log gets truncated, then i wont be able to get correct information.

Comment: As far as I'm aware dpkg doesn't keep that info. You can check `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.list` file last modification date, since it gets created when package is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Answers are (also) in the comments here https://serverfault.com/questions/175504/how-do-i-get-the-history-of-apt-get-install-on-ubuntu

And https://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline

Debian, **Ubuntu package history** :

```
$ cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -iB 1 "apt-get install <package-name>"
```

RPM based OS´s (also) `$ rpm -qa --last | grep <package-name>` (or part of name)